# Angular 12 integration with Keycloak, build problems

Tags: angular, keycloak

I'm trying to execute the following tutorial to integrate an Angular 12 application with Keycloak: [Keycloak Integration with Angular Frontend](https://sairamkrish.medium.com/keycloak-integration-part-2-integration-with-angular-frontend-f2716c696a28) (I've checked other similar tutorials and the instructions are the same).

As described in the article, I've inserted the following lines in `src\environments\environment.ts`:

```
import { KeycloakConfig } from 'keycloak-angular';

// Add here your keycloak setup infos
let keycloakConfig: KeycloakConfig = {
  url: 'http://<my-keycloak-ip:8088>/auth',
  realm: '<my-realm-name>',
  clientId: '<my-client-id>',
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "<my-client-secret>"
  }  
};

export const environment = {
...
  keycloak: keycloakConfig,
...
};
```

When I start the application with `ng serve`, I got the following build error:

```
Error: src/environments/environment.ts:14:7 - error TS2322: Type '{ url: string; realm: string; clientId: string; credentials: { secret: string; }; }' is not 
assignable to type 'KeycloakConfig'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"credentials"' does not exist in type 'KeycloakConfig'.

14       "credentials": {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
15         "secret": "<my-client-secret>"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
17       }
~~~~~~~
```

I'using Angular v12 and keylcoak-angular 8.2.0 + keycloak-js 13.0.1, in any case, below are the full `ng version` output and `package.json` contents.

`ng version`:

```
ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / ? \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 12.0.4
Node: 12.18.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.0.4
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.4
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.0.4
@schematics/angular             12.0.4
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.2.4
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "<my-angular-app>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.4",
    "admin-lte": "^3.0.5",
    "keycloak-angular": "^8.2.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^13.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't follow random "tutorials". Especially if they expose client secret in the Angular app = anyone can read that secret in the browser. So secret won't be secret anymore.

A client application is considered public when an end user could possibly view and modify the code. This includes Single-Page Apps (SPAs) or any mobile or native applications. In both cases, the application can't keep secrets from malicious users.

`Public client` (client without secret) must be used in the SPA apps and also OIDC flow, which is not using secret - `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE`. Use mature OIDC certified library e.g. https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client or configure `keycloak-js` lib properly (e.g. `checkLoginIframe: false, pkceMethod: 'S256'` - check documentation).

Answer (score 0):

the latest [library guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) does not contain any "credentials" in the configuration. try removing this piece at all, it shouldn't be there

Comment: ok, but then how am I supposed to pass the keycloak client's secret if the client's access type in keycloak is marked as "confidential"?

Comment: I believe it is no longer preconfigured and it is autogenereted