# Angular 11 with keycloak on confidential mode

Tags: angular, keycloak

I'm trying to connect my angular app to keycloak in confidential mode (i.e, with a secret) and using openid-connect protocol.

I followed some tutorials on doing this using [keycloak-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular), for reference, [this one](https://wkrzywiec.medium.com/step-by-step-guide-how-integrate-keycloak-with-angular-application-d96b05f7dfdd).

This works fine on public mode (on Access type) but not in confidential mode. In particular, it's not possible to set the property credentials on the initialize method.

```
export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
 return () =>
  keycloak.init({
    config: {
    url: environment.keycloak.issuer,
    realm: environment.keycloak.realm,
    clientId: environment.keycloak.clientId,
    //not recognize
    credentials: {
      secret: 'secret_key'
    }

  },
  initOptions: {
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    checkLoginIframe: false
  },
});
}
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62298549/keycloak-client-secret-not-provided-in-request) this feature was removed.

There is some workaround on this or should I use other lib to accomplish this?

My dependencies

```
Angular 11
"keycloak-angular": "^8.0.1"
"keycloak-js": "^10.0.2"
```

Comment: Secret in the public app? Is it really secret then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67946768/angular-12-integration-with-keycloak-build-problems/67955489#67955489

Comment: It's not a public app. Do you know if it's possible or do you suggest other lib to do it?

Comment: How SPA app can't be a public app? A client application is considered public when an end user could possibly view and modify the code. This includes Single-Page Apps (SPAs) or any mobile or native applications. In both cases, the application can't keep secrets from malicious users.

Comment: Humm, You're right? I misread the public app concept. Can you reply with the official answer saying that's not possible since it's a public app in order to accept it?